# Empty dataframe after merging CSV and geodataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, geopandas

I'm trying to add a geomtry column from a GeoJSON/gpd dataframe to a csv dataframe yet when the merge is done the resulting dataframe is empty. I've checked the dtypes of the column attempting to join on and they're both objects.

So far I've tried (grouped_gj is geodataframe and map_df2 is csv)

```
joined_gdf = grouped_gj.merge(map_df2, on='County Name')
```

and

```
new_gdf = pd.merge(grouped_gj, map_df2, on="County Name")
```

Both dataframes have the same column "County Name", however map_df2 has 2010 rows whilst grouped_gj has 67 rows which could be the issue? map_df2 contains state names that are repeated eg

```
County Name   | Date        | Covid Cases
Alachua County  Jan2020_Sum      0
Alachua County  Feb2020_Sum      0
Alachua County  Mar2020_Sum      652
...
Baker County    Jan2020_Sum      0
etc
```

I was just hoping to add the geometry from grouped_gj to map_df2, but no errors have been outputted so not sure what to try. Thanks

Comment: If you don't specify `how` for `merge()`it defaults to inner join and resulting empty df hints that `County Name`s of those data frames don't quite match. Have you checked if either of those columns have some extra trailing whitespace?

Comment: @margusl That sorted it thank you!